# Removed responsive design elements from css, but narrow mobile-width background is still showing up

Tags: html, css

I just want this to display the same on computers and on mobile devices, not doing any responsive design for this project.

I've gone through the CSS and commented out everything having to do with a mobile version.

However, my site is still displaying incorrectly on mobile devices. The content is showing as desired (for the most part), but the background is shrunk and narrow like it is trying to display at the mobile page-width.

I've tried multiple devices, so this is not a cache problem.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

http://www.carolinafarmstewards.org

Here's an image of what it looks like on my phone:
[image: website screengrab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` from the head.

Comment: Duh! I feel dumb. Thank you!